# AccessibilityElements not working in TableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uiaccessibility

I'm trying to override the standard way of voice speaking a cell.

If I use do nothing (let the storyboard do the magic) it will access all the elements in a cell. 
But when I try to change the order of voice speaking of a cell it doesn't work.

See my code below:

```
class OverviewTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet weak var messageIndicator: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var dateLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lastMessagelabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var profileImage: UIImageView!

   override func awakeFromNib() {
       super.awakeFromNib()

       accessibilityElements = [messageIndicator, dateLabel, nameLabel, lastMessagelabel]
   }

   override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
       super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
   }
}
```

Also when I try to do disable al the elements through storyboard and do it programmatically is doesn't work at all.

```
    messageIndicator.isAccessibilityElement = true
    dateLabel.isAccessibilityElement = true
    nameLabel.isAccessibilityElement = true
    lastMessagelabel.isAccessibilityElement = true
```

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's fairly uncommon to have subelements of a cell be accessibility elements of their own. If you look at other apps on your device (Apple's own apps usually have good accessibility) you will see that in most cases the table view cell is a single accessibility element that contains all the information from its subelements in its label.

You can achieve this by making the cell an accessibility element and the subelements *not* be accessibility elements. Then, you construct a custom accessibility label out of the different pieces of information in the order that you find most suitable.

Comment: Hi David, I like your answer, and your totally right. I probably asked the question the wrong way. The thing is now that it speaks all elements, when selected on a cel, like a standard a+b+c+d. I just want to change this order. Example: a+c+d.

I can't fix this with the `accessibilityElements` as shown above in the Custom Cell. How can I change that order?

Comment: Part of being an accessibility container is that that element can't be an accessibility element itself. You might also have to set the `accessibilityContainer` property of the sub elements.